# c++ add value to multi-array error in conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, character, element

I am trying to add some text values into an array such as

- **some value 1**
- **some value 2**
- **some value 3**
- etc..

here is the procedure i follow:

```
char values_array[3][80];
values_array[0][80] = "Rock and Rolla";
cout << values_array[0] << endl;
```

and **i get the following error:**

```
invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char'
```

Comment: Well, you have a two dimensional array of characters, not strings.

Comment: how can i make the array be able to use strings with spaces but mostly many characters

Comment: this is a very basic question that you should be able to resolve by yourself. Invest some time, ours isn't cheaper than yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states exactly what the problem is. The assignment is attempting to assign a `const char*`, the type of string string literal, to a `char`, the type of `values_array[0][80]`. The ***incorrect*** immediate response would be change it to:

```
values_array[0] = "Rock and Rolla";
```

but this is also incorrect as it is not possible to assign arrays. Either copy the string literal or, preferably, use a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> values;
values.push_back("Rock and Rolla");

std::cout << values[0] << std::endl;
```

Using a `std::vector<std::string>` eliminates the hard-coded limit on the number of strings that can be stored and potential buffer-overrun problems when copying the string literals (or other strings) into the array elements.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign `"Rock and Rolla"`, which is a `char[]`, into `values_array[0][80]`, which has type `char`. What you probably want is:

```
char values_array[3][80]
strcpy(values_array[0], "Rock and Rolla");
```

Nevertheless, you should use `std::string` instead of `char*` to represent strings in C++. The code would then be:

```
std::string values_array[3];
values_array[0] = "Rock and Rolla";
```